# XNA 4.0 game crashes when adding sprite at runtime

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, xna

I am relatively new to programming (this is a hobby), especially C#, and I'm trying to develop a simple snake game-clone in XNA 4.0 for Windows Phone 8.

I am hitting a rather strange issue that when I run the following code the game crashes on my device (and the emulator as well) but the VS window shows it as running. The problem doesnt seem to be memory related which I checked by running the profiler tool.

The error arises when I try to add a unit to the snake as it collides with the food. I have tried using the responsible code inline within Update() and also  as a separate function in the Game1 class, but both of them have the same problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace aaaSnake_1
{
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
///////////////////////////////////
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    SpriteManager spriteManager;

    foodunits food;
    List<snakeunits> snake = new List<snakeunits>();



    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        graphics.IsFullScreen = true;
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        // Frame rate is 30 fps by default for Windows Phone.
        TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromTicks(333333 *2);

        // Extend battery life under lock.
        InactiveSleepTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);


    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        TouchPanel.EnabledGestures = GestureType.VerticalDrag | GestureType.HorizontalDrag;
        //spriteManager = new SpriteManager(this);
        //Components.Add(spriteManager); // Avoid the goddamn spritemanager like hell
        //grow(snake);

        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        food = new foodunits(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures/block"), new Vector2(300, 300), 50, new Vector2(0, 0));
        snake.Add(new snakeunits(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures/block"), new Vector2(50, 300), 10, new Vector2(10, 0)));
    }



    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        // code for the touch part


        Boolean IsHead = true;
        Vector2 PreviousUnitSpeed = new Vector2(0, 0);
        Vector2 PreviousUnitPosition = new Vector2(0, 0);

        //snake update
        foreach (units unit in snake)
        {
            PreviousUnitPosition = unit.position;
            PreviousUnitSpeed = unit.speed;

            //update the head directions
            if (IsHead == true)
            {   // Head = Needs special consideration with respect to direction
                IsHead = false;
                if (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
                {
                    GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
                    switch (gesture.GestureType)
                    {
                        case GestureType.HorizontalDrag:
                            if (Math.Sign(gesture.Delta.X) != 0)
                            {
                                unit.speed.X = 10f * Math.Sign(gesture.Delta.X);
                                unit.speed.Y = 0f;
                            }
                            break;

                        case GestureType.VerticalDrag:
                            if (Math.Sign(gesture.Delta.Y) != 0)
                            {
                                unit.speed.Y = 10f * Math.Sign(gesture.Delta.Y);
                                unit.speed.X = 0f;
                            }
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }

                // grow snake if needed
                if (unit.position == food.position)
                {
                    Random X = new Random();
                    Random Y = new Random();
                    food.position.X = (float) Math.Floor(X.Next(0, Window.ClientBounds.Height - 10)/10) * 10;
                    food.position.Y = (float) Math.Floor(Y.Next(0, Window.ClientBounds.Width - 10)/10) * 10;
                    //snake.Add(new snakeunits(
                    //    Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures/block"),
                    //    PreviousUnitPosition, 10, PreviousUnitSpeed));

                    /// debug
                    snake.Add(new snakeunits(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures/block"), new Vector2(100, 100), 10, new Vector2(0, 10)));
                    //grow(snake);
                    /// debug ends 
                }

            }


            unit.position += unit.speed;
            // temporary hacks to not let the game exit on crash - bounce back for now
            if (unit.position.X > Window.ClientBounds.Height - 10f || unit.position.X < 0)    // 10f is simply the block size in pixels
            {
                unit.speed.X *= -1;
            }
            if (unit.position.Y > Window.ClientBounds.Width - 10f || unit.position.Y < 0)
            {
                unit.speed.Y *= -1;
            }
            // temporrary hacks end


        }


        //direction of head
        // rest follow head
        // ate food ?


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Turquoise);
        spriteBatch.Begin();
        food.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
        foreach (units unit in snake)
            unit.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    private void grow(List<units> snake)
    {
        snake.Add(new snakeunits(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures/block"), new Vector2(100, 100), 10, new Vector2(0, 10)));
    }

}

}
```

The line thats casing the error is

```
                    /// debug
                snake.Add(new snakeunits(Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures/block"), new Vector2(100, 100), 10, new Vector2(0, 10)));
                //grow(snake);
                /// debug ends
```

Other files included in the project (fairly basic with nothing more than a constructor)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input.Touch;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace aaaSnake_1
{
abstract class units
{
    Texture2D textureImage;
    int collisionOffset;
    int timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
    int millisecondsPerFrame;
    protected const int defaultMillisecondsPerFrame = 16;
    public Vector2 speed;
    public Vector2 position;

    public units(Texture2D textureImage,
                    Vector2 position,
                    int collisionOffset,
                    Vector2 speed)
        : this(textureImage, position, collisionOffset, speed, defaultMillisecondsPerFrame)
    {
    }

    public units(Texture2D textureImage,
                    Vector2 position,
                    int collisionOffset,
                    Vector2 speed,
                    int millisecondsPerFrame)
    {
        this.textureImage = textureImage;
        this.position = position;
        this.collisionOffset = collisionOffset;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.millisecondsPerFrame = millisecondsPerFrame;
    }

    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
    {
    }

    public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(textureImage, position, Color.White);
    }

    public abstract Vector2 direction
    {
        get;
    }

    public Rectangle collisonRect()
    {
        return new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, collisionOffset, collisionOffset);
    }

}
}
```

And

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;


namespace aaaSnake_1
{
class foodunits : units
{
    public foodunits(Texture2D textureImage,
      Vector2 position,
      int collisionOffset,
      Vector2 speed)
        : base(textureImage, position, collisionOffset, speed)
    {
    }

    public foodunits(Texture2D textureImage,
              Vector2 position,
              int collisionOffset,
              Vector2 speed,
              int millisecondsPerFrame)
        : base(textureImage, position, collisionOffset, speed, millisecondsPerFrame)
    {
    }

    public override Vector2 direction
    {
        get { return speed; }
    }


}
}
```

And

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace aaaSnake_1
{
class snakeunits : units
{
    public snakeunits(Texture2D textureImage,
              Vector2 position,
              int collisionOffset,
              Vector2 speed)
        : base(textureImage, position, collisionOffset, speed)
    {
    }

    public snakeunits(Texture2D textureImage,
              Vector2 position,
              int collisionOffset,
              Vector2 speed,
              int millisecondsPerFrame)
        : base(textureImage, position, collisionOffset, speed, millisecondsPerFrame)
    {
    }

    public override Vector2 direction
    {
        get { return speed; }
    }




}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: There is NO explicit error of any kind - the game just exits back to the homsescreen on the device/emulator but VS still shows the program as running (the pause, stop buttons are active).

EDIT 2:

Solved, although, not exactly solved.

Added a boolean flag instead of trying to add the snakeunit inside the `if` loop for the head. And used the boolean to add the unit later, just above the `base.update();` call :-

```
if (unit.position == food.position)
                {
                    ShouldGrow = true;
                    Random X = new Random();
                    Random Y = new Random();
                    food.position.X = (float)Math.Floor(X.Next(0, Window.ClientBounds.Height - 10) / 10) * 10;
                    food.position.Y = (float)Math.Floor(Y.Next(0, Window.ClientBounds.Width - 10) / 10) * 10;
                }
```

And

```
        if (ShouldGrow)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Entering snake growth");
            snake.Add(new snakeunits(snakeskin, PreviousUnitPosition2, 10, new Vector2 (0f,0f)));
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exiting snake growth");
        }
            base.Update(gameTime);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading all the textures in loadcontent. For example:

```
Texture2d snaketexture;

protected override void LoadContent()
{
   snaketexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(@"Textures/block");
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
   snake.Add(new snakeunits(snaketexture, new Vector2(100, 100), 10, new Vector2(0, 10)))
}
```

In your case it wouldnt matter if all the snake parts carried a reference to the same texture.

Edit: just realized the reason for your crash its because you put stuff in your list while iterating through it.

```
foreach (units unit in snake)
{
     snake.Add(new snakeunits(snaketexture, new Vector2(100, 100), 10, new Vector2(0, 10)))
}
```

This is the reason your problem was solved when moving the snake.add to the bottom of the function. You could solve this by creating a temporary list and then when done iterating your snake list you append your temporary list to your snake list.

```
List<snakeunits>tmpList = new List<snakeunits>();
foreach (units unit in snake)
{
     tmpList.Add(new snakeunits(snaketexture, new Vector2(100, 100), 10, new Vector2(0, 10)))
}

snake.AddRange(tmpList);
```

Comment: That didnt help, but definitely is a better way to code. 
Still debugging the issue at hand...

Comment: I have got around the issue here in this question, but I have have no idea why/how. Added the workaround at the end of the question.

I am new to programming in any serious sense of the word, and VS for some reason doesn even let me add a watch to a variable. So all down to using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`, but it slows down the emulator crazy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was pretty stupid from my part. :)
Will surely check out the article on debugging too.